# How to fix an unexpected end of file error in bash?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

The code saying that there is "unexpected end of file" error in line 16. Could someone please tell me my mistake?

```
#!/bin/bash

total=0
for i in `grep 01/Oct/2006 log.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail`;
do if [[ $i =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    total=$(( $total + $i )); fi

for i in `grep 01/Oct/2006 log.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2,3 | sed -E 's/(\S*) (\S*)/\2 - \1/' | nl -s'. '`;

do 
    if ! [[ $i =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];
        then
            printf $i;
            printf " ";
        else
            printf " $i - $(echo "scale=0; $i * 100 / $total" | bc )%% \n" ;
    fi
done
```

Comment: the problem are `"` in line 15 `printf " $i - 0$(echo "scale=0; $i / $total" | bc)%% " ;`

Comment: @Szczerba No they don't :) Although I miscounted the same way at first, too.

Comment: @Amadan true, counting to 4 is not so easy before taking a coffee

Comment: paste your script to [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for diagnosing syntax errors

Comment: Once that's fixed, you'll need to fix `$total += $i` - no such thing in bash. `total=$((total + i))` or `let "total = total + i"` would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first `for` loop lacks a `done`.

Here's a working version with improved formatting (but with all original flaws and bugs left inside, I just fixed the one issue asked for here):

```
#!/bin/bash

$total;
for i in $(
  grep 01/Oct/2006 log.txt | 
    cut -d' ' -f1 |
      sort |
        uniq -c |
          tail);
do
  if [[ $i =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
  then
    $total += $i
  fi
done

for i in $(
  grep 01/Oct/2006 log.txt |
    cut -d' ' -f1 |
      sort |
        uniq -c |
          sort -rn |
            head -10 |
              tr -s ' ' |
                cut -d' ' -f2,3 |
                  sed -E 's/(\S*) (\S*)/\2 - \1/' |
                    nl -s'. ')
do 
  if ! [[ $i =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];
  then
    printf " $i - ";
  else
    printf " $i - 0$(echo "scale=0; $i / $total" | bc)%% " ;
  fi
done
```

Comment: `$total += $i` is invalid, parameters/commands should not be expanded directly in `printf` format strings, and it's not a great idea to read the output of those pipelines with `for` (`while read` would be more appropriate).

Comment: Sure.  I hope nobody thinks I approve of the code just because I reformatted it and fixed one bug (the one asked for).  EDIT: changed my answer to make that clear.